# What is the variance of this unbiased estimator for a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, parameter-estimation

I have been spending some time trying to make sense of:

$$ \widehat{\sigma_2^2} = \frac{1}{2}(Y_1-Y_2)^2 $$

But I don't understand it, specifically the squared part, I don't think I can apply the variance properties if it's squared.

Comment: Assuming $X_1$ and $X_2$ are iid, it will depend on the distribution, and in particular its fourth moment about the mean, or something related to it such as the kurtosis and standard deviation.  For a normal distribution, the fourth moment about the mean is $3\sigma^4$ but other distributions will have other values.  The actual calculation is not difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac14E[(Y_1-Y_2)^4] &=\frac14E[((Y_1-\mu)-(Y_2-\mu))^4] \\
&=\frac14\sum_{i=0}^4\binom{4}{i}E[ (Y_1-\mu)^i]E[(Y_2-\mu)^{4-i}] \\
&=\frac14 \left(3\sigma^4 +6(\sigma^2)(\sigma^2) +3\sigma^4 \right)\\
&=3\sigma^4
\end{align}

Hence

$$Var\left( \frac12 (Y_1-Y_2)^2\right)=3\sigma^4 - \sigma^4 = 2\sigma^4$$